# Updating specific attribute of an ArrayList item

Tags: java, arraylist

Item has `name`, `price`, `condition` attributes. I want to keep the `price`and `condition`but replace the `name`.

For now I figured out this by creating new object but I think this is not best option. I just want to change one field of ArrayList item

```
public void modify(String name) {
    for (Item i : item) {
        if (i.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(name)) {
            int position = item.indexOf(i);
            System.out.println("New name: ");
            String newName = in.nextLine();
            Item updated = new Item(newName, i.getPrice(), i.getCondition(), i.getSize());
            item.set(position, updated);

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't have to insert a new item to `ArrayList`

```
public void modify(String name) {
    for (Item i : item) {
        if (i.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(name)) {
            System.out.println("New name: ");
            String newName = in.nextLine();
            i.setName(newName);
        }
    }
}
```

It's supposed you have set methods for each field. Then you can update name, price, size this way

Comment: one could also check if the new name is empty or null and then only set the new one.

Comment: something like this .. if(StringUtils.isNotEmpty(newName)) { i.setName(newName); }

Answer (score 6):

You can have an `updateName` method in the `Item` class, and then only update the object's name:

```
item.get(index).updateName(newName);
```

`item.get(index)` returns an `Item` object, on which you apply the `updateName` method.

Comment: So i have to add methods to updating everything? I actually want to make method 'update' and then you can choose what you want to update (Name, Price, Condition)

Comment: @Sharkmen You don't have to construct a new object each time you want to modify a property. That's why you have "setters". Instead of `updateName` you can call it `setName`.

Comment: @Sharkmen I hope I clarified that for you, and now you know a better approach. Keep it going!

Comment: @Maroun how do you find out the index of the item by the name?

Answer (score 0):

Actually after finding the item you don't need to iterate though the whole list for no purpose, so it's better to extract your find method as a static function into Item class like

```
public void modify(String name) {
    System.out.println("New name: ");
    String newName = in.nextLine();
    Item itemToModify = Item.findByName(item, name);
    if(itemToModify != null) {
        itemToModify.setName(newName);
    } else {
        System.out.println("Item not found with that name!");
    }
}
```

Item.java

```
public static Item findByName(Collection<Item> items, String name) {
    for(Item item : items) {
        if(item.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(name)) {
            return item;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Imagine if you have like a million items in your collection, and you want to update the secong. You iterate through te remaining 999.998 for nothing.